# How to change the child content of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into an issue and I am unable to "reach" the child of this div:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#memory_board{
    background:#CCC;
    border:#999 1px solid;
    width:800px;
    height:540px;
    padding:24px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
div#memory_board > div{
    background: url(http://image.png) no-repeat center;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    width:71px;
    height:71px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:64px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

What I am trying to do is change the background of all `div#board > div` with a button.

I tried this:

```
function imageChange(){  
document.getElementsByTag("memory_board").style.background="url(http://image.png)";
}
```

But of course, it doesn't work. I tried various combinations but nothing seems to work. Any tips? (I do have a button which calls the function later so that's definitely not the problem!)

This is the full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/o72z8dqv/

UPDATE:
Solved, thanks!
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2p7sckjt/2/) is the updated working code.

Comment: can you add the html part too. That will be more helpful

Comment: Create a second class and just switch the classes? Also, if you put the rule one the parent, you only need to change the parents class instead of each childs. If you can't reach the child, maybe there's multiple nestings before the div you're trying to target: parent > child only works if child is a direct child of the parent.

Comment: can you use jquery ?

Comment: board is not a tag as your css convenes its an id so use `getElementsById` instead of  `getElementsByTag` so it will become `document.getElementsById("board").style.background = "url('http://image.png')";`

Comment: @AmanRawat make that an anwser

Comment: Updated and @AmanRawat I have tried that but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o72z8dqv/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and then you need to use loop to change style of each child `div` because it returns `NodeList`

```js
function imageChange() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("#board > div");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/350x150/333333')";
  }
}
```

```css
div#board > div {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff') no-repeat center;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="imageChange()">BUtton</button>
<div id="board">
  <div>Div</div>
  <div>Div</div>
</div>
```

You can also use [`Array.from()`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/780/) or [`Array.prototype.slice.call()`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/781/) and then you can use `forEach` loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on your css, I guess, "board" is your id. So please just replace `getElementsByTag("board")` by `getElementById("board")`